# Facebook Share dialog always shows Captcha only on Android

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, share, captcha

I have a cross platform application (iOS/Android/Web) that has a 'Share' feature.
The 'Share' feature works nicely on iOS and Web builds, but on the Android platform Facebook is always showing a 'Security check' captcha to the user before presenting the Share form:

[image: Captcha]

The arguments being passed to [FB.Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/3/FB.Feed) are as follows:

- link: `"http://apps.facebook.com/<my_app_id>"`
- linkName: `"Solitaire"` (my app name)
- picture: `"http://casual-solitaire.herokuapp.com/Resources/Facebook/ShareIcon-128x128.png"`

There are two weird things here:

1. The Captcha only happens on Android
2. If I use exactly the same parameters in `FB.Feed` but change `<my_app_id>` to another app the captcha goes away (I've test it with an app ID from another app I've published).

Looks like my app ID is 'blacklisted', does anyone know what can I do to fix that?

Comment: Hey Eduardo, do you mind sharing your app id?

Comment: No problem @Flaxfield, it is '1446984348864495'.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there has been suspicious activities with sharing that url. How long is this happening for your Android users already? It could also be with the messages that are shared together with this url.

You can appeal for blocked content here: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/244560538958131

I hope this helps you further.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try your suggestion and post feedback here if it solves my problem.